# Is it possible in Swift to make a generic extension of a Binding of a Dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, swiftui, binding

e.g. in my mind the code would read something like:

```
extension Binding where Value == Dictionary, Value.Key == AnyHashable, Value.Value == Any {
    func myFunc(key: Value.Key) {}
}
```

But while it seems like I can make an extension on a `Binding` of a *specific* `Dictionary` type, and while I can make an extension on a `Dictionary` with generic key and value types, I can't seem to figure out how to combine the two.

Comment: Can you elaborate on combine the two? My guess is you need a generic method

Comment: By "combine the two" I just mean what I said above. I want an extension for Bindings of an arbitrary Dictionary type. I can make an extension on a Binding, and I can make an extension on a generic Dictionary type, but I can't seem to figure out how to make an extension on a Binding of a generic Dictionary type.

Comment: Did you mean `extension Binding where Value == Dictionary<AnyHashable, Any>`?

Comment: @RubenMartinezJr. check the duplicate links `func myFunc<Key: Hashable, V>(key: Key) where Value == [Key: V] {`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a where clause on the extension in Swift's type system AFAIK.  It should be doable with parameterized extensions which has an [in-progress implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/25263) but hasn't seen recent activity.

You can do it if you move the where clause to the method instead of the extension:

```swift
extension Binding {
    func myFunc<K, V>(key: K) where Value == Dictionary<K, V> {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Dictionary key needs to conform to Hashable protocol